# WinUI 3, MVVM Pattern: How can I inject a service into another service?

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

## Background

I have a WinUI 3 application, created with [Template Studio for WinUI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs). It's using MVVM pattern, so I have a ViewModel which gets two Services injected using dependency injection (one being the primary data that is driving the UI, and the other being metadata).

## Code

In App.xaml.cs, I am adding the services:

```
services.AddSingleton<IJobService, JobService>();
services.AddSingleton<ITableDefinitionsService, TableDefinitionsService>();
```

In the ViewModel, I am injecting the services in the constructor:

```
public ListDetailsViewModel(IJobService jobService, ITableDefinitionsService TableDefinitionsService)
```

Later, I get my main data from the IJobService, as a `List<Job>`. I want each `Job` to have a reference to the `ITableDefinitionsService`, so that when my UI is referencing a `Job` in a `ListView` `DataTemplate`, it can retrieve information such as choice lists directly from the `Job`, so that I can use `x:Bind` and not have to mess with binding complexity.

## Question

Is it possible in MVVM to inject a service into another service, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is about **DependencyInjection**, not **MVVM**. You just need to let the service provider do its job.

You need to make sure that `JobService` has a constructor so that
the service provider can inject the registered `ITableDefinitionsService` when it instantiates `JobService`.

```cs
public class JobService
{
    public JobService(ITableDefinitionsService tableDefinitionService)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```